# "Find in Files" dialog disappears on Find All in Visual Studio 2015

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

Pressing `Ctrl+Shift+F` shows the dialog, and when clicking `Find All` the results appear in Find Results 1 as expected but the Find In Files dialog disappears. How can I make it stay visible? Docking it won't work.

Comment: I have a strong feeling that this happens by design.

Comment: There's no pin icon on this tab as there are on others.